# Remove line break in list - never seen this happen

Tags: html, css, list

I don't know what caused the break, but I'm looking for help (first unordered list): [Webpage can be found here](http://pixelperfectphotography.org/responsive/weddings.html)

My list:

- item
- item
- item

Thank you for the help in advance!

Comment: Are you talking about how the first list is on a separate line from the other two? This is because you placed the other two in their own separate row.

Comment: Sorry, the problem is the extra bullet that was created. There's just an empty space there with no content. Here's a [Screen Shot](http://i.imgur.com/vHRd9SZ.png)

Comment: It appears there is an extra li tag inside of the list... did you put that there and can you remove it?

Comment: I tried to remove it, It won't budge unfortunately. Here's a screen shot of the code: [here](http://i.imgur.com/SDpproZ.png)

Comment: It looks like you may have just figured it out. You had an unclosed `<li>` tag right before the extra bullet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the image you posted of your code, the original `<li>` tag containing "Twenty 8x10 Prints" was wrapped with another `<li>` instead of `</li>` (meaning it was unclosed and adding another), which is what caused the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what caused it, but there were hidden characters that weren't recognized by my code editor. I simply deleted everything and rewrote it exactly the same and it worked. Thanks for those that took the time to answer!